# redirect 301 after rewrie without query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have url-rewriting on my web site but doesn't work redirect

in .htacces i use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)\.php$ /news.php?link=$1 [L]
```

but if i want to do redirect 301 of a link by htaccess (Redirect 301 /news/my-story.php http://www.mywebsite.com) on home page

I see ok but on the status i see: http://www.mywebsite.com?link=my-story

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Redirect`, use mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteRule ^news/my-story.php$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

and put the rule **before** your other rule.

Comment: I putted on the first line in the .htaccess but doesn't work, there's the some errore: http://www.mywebsite.com?link=my-story